# help with span/linearindepencence/basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine whether each given tuple (i) spans $P_2$, (ii) is linearly independent, (iii) is a basis of $P_2$.

(a.) $(2−x, 1+3x−x^2 , −7x+2x^2 )$
(b.) $(1+x−x^2 , 3x+2x^2 , −1+x+4x^2 )$

I can't figure this one out.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $dim(P_2)=3$, any three linearly independent vectors would span the whole set. All it remains is to show that which of the following is a linearly independent set.

For (i)  if $c_1(2-x)+c_2(1+3x-x^2)+c_3(-7x+2x^2)=0$, then $2c_1+c_2=0,-c_1+3c_2-7c_3=0,2c_3-c_2=0$. Now if you take $c_1=-\frac{1}{2},c_2=1, c_3=\frac{1}{2}$, you will see that there exists a nonzero linear combination of the three vectors which equals zero. Hence the set is not linearly independent and they don't form a basis.

Similarly check for (ii).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  For any polynomial $a+bx+cx^2$ in $\Bbb P_2$, try to find scalars $t_1,t_2,t_3$ such that
$$t_1(2-x)+t_2(1+3x-x^2)+t_3(-7x+2x^2)=a+bx+cx^2\ .$$
This leads to an augmented matrix which we can row-reduce to echelon form,
$$\pmatrix{2&1&0&|&a\cr -1&3&-7&|&b\cr 0&-1&2&|&c\cr}
  \sim\pmatrix{-1&3&-7&|&b\cr 0&-1&2&|&c\cr 0&0&0&|&a+2b+7c\cr}\ .$$
Now you need to answer the following questions.

1. Does this system have a solution for **all** values of $a,b,c$?  What does this tell you about whether the set is a spanning set?  What does it tell you about whether the set is independent?
2. Now replace $a,b,c$ by $0,0,0$.  Does the system have a unique solution, or infinitely many?  What does this tell you about whether the set is a spanning set?  What does it tell you about whether the set is independent?

**Comment**.  The answer to two of my four "what does it tell you" questions is: it tells you nothing.  It's important to make sure you get the reasons the right way around: many people get the two problems mixed up.